# VS 2010 --- DropDownList: how to get ID but show a different column for options

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I have a quick question (hopefully quick). I'm still learning, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to get a DDL working, where my drop down shows the user one column of options, but in reality, the option they pick will use the DeviceID for that particular option in the other column. Here is what I have for my Data Source:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RetrieveComputerSQL" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SynInventory %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT DeviceID + ' ' + Computer as Combo,Computer as Computer,DeviceID AS DeviceID from Hardware">
```

Now the Hardware Table has 2 colunns.

DeviceID = IDs of the items in the table
Computer = The type of machines attached to that DeviceID

So for example, the Hardware table looks like this:

```
>Computer (Column)        DeviceID (Column)
>------------------       ----------------------   
> Thin Client                      0
> Desktop                          1
> Laptop                           2
```

Now, here is my DDL:

```
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlComputer" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    DataSourceID="RetrieveComputerSQL" DataTextField="Combo" DataValueField="Computer"                      
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Computer") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

What I want to do is still show the "friendly" name of the object, but in reality, grab the DeviceID of the selected object in the drop down box, then report that value back to my main DataSource (which is: UPDATE MainAsset SET [site] = @Site,[os] = @os,[device] = @Computer WHERE [pk] = @pk") where [device] IS my Hardware table.

I've tried this every which way I can think of, and manipulted my RetrieveComputerSQL DS in many ways. I decided to end on the "Combo" option, but nothing I've tried seems work.

Any constructive ideas or comments sure would be appreciated. Hope this all makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "where [device] IS my Hardware table"?

Comment: Actually:  what is going wrong?  DDL not displaying?  Update not working?  Desired selection value not selected in DDL?

Comment: DDL does display, and it shows the "friendly" name I want people to see, but it doesn't grab the deviceID that the friendly name belongs to when the update request is submitted. Hope that makes sense. Earlier with "[device]" is my hardware table, I mean that in my main SQL datasource where I'm pulling All of my information from, [device] is actually the Hardware table I'm using now. I threw that in there just so that information is known, but now that I did it, I'm 99% confident that it holds no water in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am very much missing something:

Set your `DataValueField` to "DeviceID" and your `DataTextField` to "Computer".  That should display as you wish.

If you want a dummy entry at the top of your DDL (which is helpful if that column has null for a value in the grid source) you would do it like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlComputer" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                DataSourceID="RetrieveComputerSQL" DataTextField="Combo" DataValueField="Computer"                      
                SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Computer") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="true">
   <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select --" Value=""/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Hi Ann. Thanks for your help. I did do what you suggested, and I received the error that I've received a few different times while trying to get this working:  "Server Error in '/' Application.

'ddlComputer' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
"

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it is that I'm missing. I understand the SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Computer") %>' shows the friendly Computer column name I have, and the DataValueField should then grab the actual ID that the user has for the SelectedValue, right?

Comment: If you're going to bind something to `SelectedValue`, it has to be something that matches one of the DeviceIDs you're binding to.  It has to be DeviceID because it's the selected *value*, not the text.  It also has to exist in the data:  if you intend to have a blank "nothing selected yet" entry in your DDL, you'll need to put an explicit `asp:ListItem` for that entry in the DDL tag.

Comment: @MikeTucker  I added an example to my answer.